# WC: Negative Stock from Order while Backorder is disabled

Tags: caching, woocommerce

This is my problem: a customer bought a product that was out of stock. So the stock went from 0 to -1.

My out of stock threshold is at 0 and back ordering is disabled with all products.
I tried to recreate the scenario on my staging site but it was not possible to me. The product is greyed out and not selectable when I set its quantity to 0.

I thought maybe some caching issue (I'm using Hummingbird) prevented it from updating the stock. So these were the further scenarios I tried:
- selecting product on single product page, set stock in back-end to 0 --> not possible
- product in basket, set stock in back-end to 0 --> not possible
- product in checkout, set stock in back-end to 0 --> not possible

Would anyone of you know how it could have happened? I'm not sure how to proceed.

thanks

Jan

Comment: There is no way to provide an adequate and correct answer to this question.  All we can do is speculate.

Answer (score 1):

After carefully reading the WooCommerce source code I think you can recreate the problem if you have two computers.

Consider a product P with stock quantity equal to 1. There are 2 different customers A and B. Customer A puts product P into his cart. Before customer A places his order customer B puts product P into his cart. Then customer A places his order reducing the stock quantity of product P to 0. Then customer B places his order reducing the stock quantity of product P to -1. Unfortunately to test this it requires two computers (or two browsers) since you need two simultaneously logged in customers. I only have one computer and don't want to install another browser.

The problem is in the function WC_Cart::add_to_cart(). It calls WC_Product::has_enough_stock() with references to only the stock quantity of the product and the quantity ordered in its cart. It doesn't not take into account the quantities of the product that exists in other carts. In fact WooCommerce should be able to do better as it has knowledge of the contents of customer A's cart when customer B adds product P to his cart A.

Of course there is a bit of a dilemma here because if WooCommerce prevents customer B from adding product P to his cart because customer A has it in his cart and customer A doesn't actual place the order then the company may have lost a sale.

Alternatively, WooCommerce can reject customer B's order when B places the order but unless I missed something I did not see any code to do that. That would seem to me to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: I tried your suggestion today and it is not the issue. The inventory is being updated and customer B sees a red note saying that product P is not in stock. I found a similar discussion here: [link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12467) only with both customers buying the product almost simultaneously. This is though not the case with me. There was no one else who bought the same product.

Comment: The behavior described in https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12467 is exactly what I deduced the WooCommerce code should do. Although, the timing isn't as critical as they indicate. The critical defect is WooCommerce allows two carts essential to contain the same stock and then doing no checking when the order is actually placed and just blindly decreasing the stock quantity. I am somewhat surprised that you cannot duplicate the behavior reported in issue 12467 as unless I have missed something the code should do exactly that. There may be other scenarios that can cause this ...

Comment: ... problem. The function WC_Product::has_enough_stock() is only called 3 times in the entire WooCommerce source code. Twice when adding a product to a cart and once before enabling the undo on a removed product - i.e., cannot add a removed product back to the cart if the stock quantity is too low. I couldn't find any code verifying sufficient stock when the order is actually placed. I read the source code quite carefully but I may have missed something. Anyway, sorry this was of no help and good luck finding an answer.

Comment: If you have time can you extract from the {wp}_comments table all rows relevant to the product in question. Unless it has been cleaned it should log all changes to stock quantity done by order manipulation by the customer or by the owner as long as the order manipulation was done with the WooCommerce API. I am actually really busy at the moment but I really would like to understand this problem and could not find any other scenario that could cause it. Maybe, the data in {wp}_comments may show something.

Comment: Specifically can you search for rows by "SELECT comment_content FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_content LIKE '%&rarr;-1%';". The &rarr; is the HTML code for right arrow. The comments look like "Stock levels reduced: The Product Title 11&rarr;7" in my database. These comments are processed by language translation so they can be mapped into some different. AFAIK all manipulations of the stock quantity via an order done by using the WooCommerce API will create entries in this table. Of course, stock quantity can be manipulated outside of an order and that would not show in this table.

Comment: I looked up the wp_comment table and got this: `Stock levels reduced: Omnium Cargo - Frame-kit - S (52), Not Just Black Metallic (499-1839)<span class="description"></span> 0&rarr;-1`. As comment_author/agent is WooCommerce' inscribed. Can't find any further information in the table though I'm also not so sure what to further look for. Also no one had ordered a similar bike recently, so there was no concurrent order with the same product.

Comment: The means that the reduction in stock from 0 to 1 was done by the function wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels() - it is the only place this comment is generated. The 0&rarr;-1 also means that WooCommerce knew that the stock quantity was 0 and reduced it anyway. So, apparently the problem is in WooCommerce itself and not some external plugin. Is there anything interesting in the wp_comments table in the rows immediately preceding or following this row. I.e., the context of this action usually indicated by additional rows around the row you found.

Comment: Try "SELECT comment_content FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID = {the order id of order where the reduction from 0->1 occurred};"

Comment: 'Also no one had ordered a similar bike recently,  ...' - this means there must be another scenario where WooCommerce does a duplicate reduction. I look for it in the source code. I have a pressing by Christmas deadline so I may be a while responding but I remain very interested in solving this.

Comment: 'Also no one had ordered a similar bike recently, ...' - then the duplicate reduction must have occurred on the same order - seems like the only possibility? Is there a "1&rarr;0" comment also for this order? This comment should exists if the duplicate reduction was done on the same order.